# Can't enable 3rd monitor on Radeon 5570 even with displayport

Tags: graphics-card, amd-catalyst

I've got an XFX Radeon 5570, which according to the box and AMDs website supports 3 monitors (eyefinity).  I'm running XP x64.

It's configured as follows

- DVI port  => dell 19" LCD
- Displayport => dell 30" LCD
- HDMI => dell 19" LCD via HDMI to DVI adapter

When I boot, the first two displays power up.  Once windows loads, the display shifts to the 2nd two displays and the first monitor goes into power saving mode.  I'm rooting around all the various options in the Catalyst Control Center and can't for the life of me find a way to enable 3 monitors?

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP only supports two simultaneous displays on these cards.  You'll need to be running Vista or 7 (or possibly Linux, I'm unsure what the driver there allows).

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/gpu50-ati-eyefinity-display-groups.aspx) AMD guide about setting up Eyefinity in Catalyst Control Centre and follow the steps.

Edit: According to various [threads](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=260&threadid=129534) in the AMD forums, it turns out that Eyefinity is not supported for Windows XP, nor does AMD plan to include XP functionality in the [future](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=260&threadid=120671&messid=1045043&parentid=1044945&FTVAR_FORUMVIEWTMP=Single).